# Suggested edit queue full

Tags: discussion, editing

[image: Suggest edit queue is full]

This is an all too common occurrence on Serverfault. Most of the times I've attempted to edit something, the queue is full. I'm aware of that it takes time to empty the queue, but having a constantly full queue is obviously not good for the health of the community.

Close votes [was recently changed](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9732/3-vote-close-hows-it-going) from 5 to 3. Would something similar for edits work? Reduce rep required for voting and submitting unvetted edits?

Comment: I decided to handle this by making a conscious effort to get 2k instead of posting here in meta. (o;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always thought it was kind of silly to require someone who has a high enough reputation to *edit a post themselves* without approval from others must get approval from others to *approve someone else's suggested edit*. One of these days I'll be bored enough to go look for why that is still a thing.

In the meantime I went to the suggested edits queue and got only 9, though presumably that's because some moderators cleaned it out. But us mere mortals are limited to reviewing 20 of them per day, so unless a lot of people go into review, they will languish.

(Update a day later: And those I reviewed yesterday are just now getting that second approval this morning.)

The problem is, there's little reason for anyone to go review things, except perhaps out of sheer altruism, and there's very little gamification on reviews either. I'm not sure this has a good solution, though I can think of some really bad solutions.

Comment: A hack is to select improve edit. Then it'll be approved instantly... ;) Apart from that; I agree with your sentiments regarding the queues. I won't claim I do too many edit reviews on those SE's where I can...

Comment: What about a second path to queue privileges that is based on reviews performed instead of internet points?

Comment: Add to that that the queues were redesigned to require even more clicks.

Comment: The game needs a larger number of players than are currently active to work as designed. Right now there are insufficient players to answer ~50% of the questions that are asked so it's not surprising that the more janitorial aspects of the game are unplayed.

Comment: The reason that multiple approvals are required is to prevent robo-reviewers from breaking the system.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't been tracking the review-queues for various reasons, thanks for bringing up the lack of community involvement in the edit queue. That's one a moderator can help clean out with less controversy (our votes are binding, for everyone else you need a vote-count) than the close/re-open queues.

Comment: i wanna support, but until i got 300 points it tooks more as a year from now, till i get 2k  i belive it take ages - dont want to tell that someone should support me but sometimes i wish getting pushed to support this site

Comment: now after risking a lot, I gained the first access to the review queue, and surprise, if I suggest an edit I will add someone else to another queue to accept my review. sadly... Enough that even and at this point I a agree to all, that not enough players are playing the game